# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: c#, installation

I have a solution that consists of 47 projects. There is an installer project that generates a setup.exe file and an msi-file. Running the setup.exe would install the Windows Service without any problem until today. Now I get the error:

> Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.

After googling a bit, it seems that I have do do a clean/rebuild on the project that is not up to date. How do I see which it is? How can I see the LoaderExceptions property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look at the fusion logs : go to the Visual Studio command line and run fuslogvw.exe. Turn logging on, and then re-run the setup. You should see the modules that the runtime can't load.

This is the same information as the LoaderExceptions.

Comment: Thank you, but I currently have another problem before I can debug it. I need to uninstall the old version first, but there is some problems...